# Format position of title and subtitle in ggplotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have created the following plot using `plotly` in `R`.

[image]

I would like to align the title and subtitle to the left side, similarly to what's done in the plot attached below. Also looking for some advice on how I can avoid having the top of the title being cut off/the subtitle not overlapping with the box.

[image]

Here is a reproductible of `dataset`

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 
17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444), class = "Date"), Annual = c(-1.2, 
1.6, -1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 2.3, 0.6, -1.7, 1.2, 2.2, 0.5, 2.8, 
1.6, -0.1, 3.2, 1.1, 0, 0.9, 0.4, 1, 4.7, 0.4, -3.6, -0.6, -1.5, 
-2.3, -0.4, -3.5, -6.3, -1.9, -2.1, -5.2, -49.1, -32.4, -15.8, 
-10.6)), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and the code I've used below

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,lubridate,ggthemes,readxl,tsibble,plotly)

p1 <- ggplot(dataset, aes(Date, Annual)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2, col = '#4f042e') +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed', col = 'red',size = 1) +
  labs(y = 'Annual Percentage Change (%)') +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(head(dataset$Date, 1), 
                            tail(dataset$Date, 1),
                            by = '6 months'), date_labels = '%b-%Y') 

p1 %>% ggplotly() %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = paste0('Industrial Production Index, Manufacturing',
                                    '<br>',
                                    '<sup>',
                                    'Manufacturing has experienced a partial normalisation since the historic lows recorded in April',
                                    '</sup>')))
```

Comment: In order to align title to the left you should use `title_x=0` while to have more space between title and box you should modify your top `margin`.

Comment: Thanks @rpanai, I just ended up adding ```x=0.01``` to the list in ```layout``` and that solved the left alignment issue. Adding the ```margin``` argument also worked